# Sort By Descending upon lookup column

Tags: list, lookup-column

I have a lookup column in multiple lists that points to a list of dates. These dates go in ascending order, and since the list posts are sequential, the older dates start to become irrelavent, forcing users that add new list items to scroll through to the bottom of the drop-down box to select the lastest date.

As you can tell this can be very tedious, all I need is for the lookup column to sort by DESCENDING order, and I've tried fooling with the lookup list's view, but I think it disregards the view and only looks at the list items.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not do this using jQuery? I also thought you could set up a separate view of the list that has the dates and just use the date field and set its sort order and then use that view for the lookup.

Comment: I could possibly use jQuery, you tell me. I'm not an expert in jQuery. This is for the NewForm.aspx page for the List library. Also, the view cannot be changed from the NewForm.

Comment: I think that jQuery can get this done. Here is an example I found on the web. http://rickyrosario.com/blog/sorting-dropdown-select-options-using-jquery/

Comment: glad it helped!

Comment: Hey, could you post your sharepoint-adapted solution, please?